# jQuery equations for dropdown selections

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

Ok, well basically I have a jquery dialog, in that dialog it asks questions such as, are you planning to stay on campus, are you an in-state/out-of-state student, and how many years are you planning on attending. Based on the users selection, I want it to total up the cost by the value of (tutuion + Room & Board) * years based on the dropdowns.

This is what I have so far..

```
if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + username.val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $('#studenttut>option:selected').val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $('#campusrb>option:selected').val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $('#yearsatten>option:selected').val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
```

Those are my values in jquery, is there a simple equation I can throw in to calculate the total cost of college? Please and Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the HTML of your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add many values in javascript you must use parseint()

Example:
`total = parseInt(student.opt1)+parseInt(student.opt2);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Please post links to better repositories than http://w3fools.com - MDN for example

Comment: Well, where and how would I use that with the data already being posted like $('#studenttut>option:selected').val() + $('#campusrb>option:selected').val() * $('#yearsatten>option:selected').val() and it echoing the total.

Comment: Try this code:`var total = parseInt($('#studenttut>option:selected').val()) + parseInt($('#campusrb>option:selected').val()) * parseInt($('#yearsatten>option:selected').val());

$("#total").text(total); // insert into your html element id total.`

Comment: So id throw var total = parseInt($('#studenttut>option:selected').val()) + parseInt($('#campusrb>option:selected').val()) * parseInt($('#yearsatten>option:selected').val()); $("#total").text(total); in the <script> then <div id="total" ></div> in the html?

Comment: Alright sweet, thanks. Thats kinda what I wanted, just got to integrate it with my jquery code and dialog.